# Detect locale by the string version of date in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

I am getting JSON from a website's API and they have this as one of the values: `/Date(1490236632140)/`

I tried cropping out everything except the numbers and using the date function to echo the date but it seems to be in a different locale because it echoed this: `9/19/49193`

I have no idea how to echo this as the correct date, it is supposed to be `3/23/2017`. I tried using the C locale to see if it was a C++ or C# formated date but it isn't. Here is a code snippet of all that i am doing.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f3f40fcaa06f25f908ee18c269389429e122222c

Comment: That's a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. See https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: divide it by 1000 first. then cast into date.

Comment: for code examples, check this https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: @Dimi thank you that actually worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's timestamp in milisecond started from [Jan 1, 1970(called epoch time)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

In C#, you can simply convert it into datetime in following way :

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Math.Round(1490236632140 / 1000d));
```

In PHP, you can convert it into correct date time in following way :

```
$seconds = 1490236632140  / 1000;
$date = date("m/d/Y", $seconds);
```